# Cómo puedo añadir espacio después de las comas en la lista de elementos?

Tags: javascript, ejs

Quisiera poder editar el texto del array generado a partir de la venta añadida, darle espacio luego de las comas y modificar el formato del texto.

```
function addSale() {
    if (validAll()) {
        const venta = {
            date: date.value,
            prodCode: prodCode.value,
            prodPrice: prodPrice.value,
            quant: quant.value
        }
```

Se crea el objeto con los datos de la venta

```
        sales.push(venta);
        console.log(sales);
        lista.innerHTML +=   Object.values(venta) + "<br>"

        resetValues();
    }   
}
```

[image: así se ve una vez añadida]

Comment: No queda muy claro lo que quieres hacer... ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado y el error? Véase [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza template string:

```javascript
const venta = {
  date: date.value,
  prodCode: prodCode.value,
  prodPrice: prodPrice.value,
  quant: quant.value
} 

sales.push(venta);
lista.innerHTML += `
  <p class="whatever">
    <b>${venta.date}</b>: 
    <span class="someclass">${venta.prodCode}</span>
    | ${prodPrice}
    | ${quant}
  </p>
`;
```